# Displaying first three hundred (300) words of a string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement for displaying first 300 words (NOT letters) of a string in Oracle. Please note that the string column can have less or more then 300 words. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using regular expressions.  Something like this:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '^([^ ] +){300}$')
```

The exact definition depends on what you mean by "word".

Comment: This approach does not work for me. Testing on a VARCHAR2 column with about 20 words.

Comment: @Drumbeg . . try replacing `{300}` with `{0,300}` or using a value like 15 if you have 20 words.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that a word is made up of alpha-numeric characters, hyphens and apostrophes then you can do this:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SENTENCES ( SENTENCE ) AS
SELECT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras gravida mattis dignissim. Aliquam a neque imperdiet, faucibus ex vel, fringilla nulla. Etiam eu diam sed enim dapibus bibendum. Cras faucibus molestie dignissim. Sed nec ligula mollis mauris pellentesque porttitor. Sed eget convallis odio. Vestibulum maximus justo nec ante accumsan, a placerat augue aliquet.

In rhoncus quis lacus eu fermentum. Etiam pretium commodo porttitor. Maecenas tristique lobortis odio, in fermentum est iaculis nec. Fusce rutrum malesuada lacus, eget accumsan quam malesuada quis. Mauris tempor turpis nec felis cursus convallis. Aliquam ac blandit arcu. Fusce dapibus elementum enim, auctor mattis justo iaculis ut. Etiam sit amet elit lobortis, eleifend quam sed, ultricies nisi. Etiam sit amet risus quam. Ut euismod, dui sed cursus pharetra, turpis leo egestas quam, non pharetra urna ipsum ac augue. Nulla quis tempor ante, in egestas sem. Nunc orci ex, sodales in ultrices in, scelerisque et massa.

Aenean massa felis, molestie eu varius sed, accumsan ut neque. Proin laoreet, quam sit amet aliquam lacinia, tortor leo venenatis velit, quis vestibulum neque enim eu augue. Mauris elementum augue eget velit iaculis mattis tempor et ante. Praesent nec felis eu dolor hendrerit finibus eu sit amet nulla. Integer ultricies justo vel placerat molestie. Etiam hendrerit, augue vel aliquet porttitor, erat est gravida nisl, sed malesuada mauris mauris eget lorem. Fusce in placerat quam. Praesent ante urna, rutrum nec ante eu, viverra hendrerit ex. Mauris finibus, dolor pharetra laoreet commodo, erat arcu lacinia mauris, sed bibendum magna mi id felis. Aenean eget sagittis arcu. Quisque scelerisque ipsum sem, vel blandit quam sodales nec. Curabitur varius erat dui, eget accumsan nisl aliquam a. Sed vehicula mollis arcu sed sodales.

Duis bibendum arcu eu est ornare auctor. Sed sed massa ultrices, vestibulum arcu id, porttitor ex. Praesent dignissim arcu mauris, id condimentum ex mollis vel. Duis tincidunt, eros vel molestie semper, dolor orci suscipit turpis, at aliquam urna nunc in leo. Quisque faucibus tortor pulvinar nibh tristique malesuada. Proin aliquet lectus et velit molestie cursus. Curabitur tincidunt ante nec pulvinar semper. Aliquam finibus finibus rutrum. Nullam vel molestie nisi. In varius tortor id neque bibendum tincidunt convallis eget metus. In pellentesque condimentum facilisis. Proin sit amet libero mi. Sed mollis sit amet est eu vehicula. In risus ante, mollis facilisis tortor a, luctus porta nisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas ipsum nisl, auctor eu mauris vel, imperdiet condimentum justo.

Nam eu faucibus urna. Sed vitae mi ac mauris faucibus posuere. Donec aliquam dignissim lacus, quis ullamcorper metus suscipit eget. Nam vitae dignissim erat, a ultricies sapien. Aenean viverra vel velit ac facilisis. Vestibulum pretium orci consectetur, tincidunt nunc a, imperdiet ligula. Proin vitae tellus sit amet eros condimentum porta. Donec sed lectus vehicula, varius nulla at, varius lorem.

In sodales pulvinar ante, et mattis libero pellentesque in. Cras scelerisque hendrerit imperdiet. Nam feugiat dolor eget tempor congue. Etiam nisl neque, lobortis vel tristique interdum, euismod et velit. Mauris consequat nunc velit, non placerat ligula pharetra sed. Donec interdum rutrum facilisis. Etiam vel est diam. Vestibulum porta, sem et consectetur vulputate, augue nulla imperdiet erat, vitae ornare lorem dui sit amet erat. Ut rhoncus nibh vel tortor placerat, vitae posuere lorem dapibus. Praesent pulvinar lorem ut ante tincidunt iaculis. Etiam non metus vel tellus viverra molestie eu in dolor. Aenean ut finibus turpis. Mauris quis ante dignissim, viverra nulla in, fermentum purus.

Donec porta pulvinar purus ac tincidunt. Etiam ut ullamcorper felis. Nulla quis nulla arcu. Morbi accumsan lacus ut est congue, vel aliquet metus lobortis. Mauris mollis dolor eget suscipit efficitur.' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( Sentence, '^((.*?[A-Za-z0-9-'']+){0,300}).*$', '\1', 1, 1, 'n')
FROM   Sentences
```

**Result**

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(SENTENCE,'^((.*?[A-ZA-Z0-9-'']+){0,300}).*$','\1',1,1,'N')                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras gravida mattis dignissim. Aliquam a neque imperdiet, faucibus ex vel, fringilla nulla. Etiam eu diam sed enim dapibus bibendum. Cras faucibus molestie dignissim. Sed nec ligula mollis mauris pellentesque porttitor. Sed eget convallis odio. Vestibulum maximus justo nec ante accumsan, a placerat augue aliquet.                                                                   

In rhoncus quis lacus eu fermentum. Etiam pretium commodo porttitor. Maecenas tristique lobortis odio, in fermentum est iaculis nec. Fusce rutrum malesuada lacus, eget accumsan quam malesuada quis. Mauris tempor turpis nec felis cursus convallis. Aliquam ac blandit arcu. Fusce dapibus elementum enim, auctor mattis justo iaculis ut. Etiam sit amet elit lobortis, eleifend quam sed, ultricies nisi. Etiam sit amet risus quam. Ut euismod, dui sed cursus pharetra, turpis leo egestas quam, non pharetra urna ipsum ac augue. Nulla quis tempor ante, in egestas sem. Nunc orci ex, sodales in ultrices in, scelerisque et massa.

Aenean massa felis, molestie eu varius sed, accumsan ut neque. Proin laoreet, quam sit amet aliquam lacinia, tortor leo venenatis velit, quis vestibulum neque enim eu augue. Mauris elementum augue eget velit iaculis mattis tempor et ante. Praesent nec felis eu dolor hendrerit finibus eu sit amet nulla. Integer ultricies justo vel placerat molestie. Etiam hendrerit, augue vel aliquet porttitor, erat est gravida nisl, sed malesuada mauris mauris eget lorem. Fusce in placerat quam. Praesent ante urna, rutrum nec ante eu, viverra hendrerit ex. Mauris finibus, dolor pharetra laoreet commodo, erat arcu lacinia mauris, sed bibendum magna mi id felis. Aenean eget sagittis arcu. Quisque scelerisque ipsum sem, vel blandit quam sodales nec. Curabitur varius erat dui, eget accumsan nisl aliquam a. Sed vehicula mollis arcu sed sodales.                                                                   

Duis bibendum arcu eu est ornare auctor. Sed sed massa ultrices, vestibulum arcu id, porttitor ex. Praesent dignissim arcu mauris, id condimentum ex
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function `instr`. Its 4-th parameter indicates occurrence of a symbol. `instr(my_string, ' ', 1, 300)` returns position of a 300-th space symbol in the string `my_string`. Result of this function you can use in the function `substr`:

```
substr(my_string, 1, instr(my_string, ' ', 1, 300))
```

If string contains less then 300 space symbols, function `instr` returns 0, take care about that.